# Getting different results in neo4j when executing queries line by line

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have just started using neo4j and I am following [this](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/#_introduction) tutorial. I am trying to execute the queries below, however I am getting different results when running each line individually and when running the 3 lines together.

```
CREATE (sally:Person { name: 'Sally', age: 32 })

CREATE (john:Person { name: 'John', age: 27 })

CREATE (sally)-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->(john)
```

[image]

Could someone give me an indication of what could be causing this issue please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute the queries separately, the variable names (`sally`, `john`) will not be carried between the queries. Which means that your third query is interpreted without variables `sally` and `john` bound to anything:

```
CREATE (sally)-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->(john)
```

So, you would achieve the same if you wrote:

```
CREATE (node1)-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->(node2)
```

Or even omitted all variable names:

```
CREATE ()-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->()
```

You can fix this multiple ways:

1.: Use a single query to make sure that its lines are not executed separately.

```
CREATE
  (sally:Person { name: 'Sally', age: 32 }),
  (john:Person { name: 'John', age: 27 }),
  (sally)-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->(john)
```

2.: Use `MATCH` to find the previously inserted nodes.

```
CREATE (sally:Person { name: 'Sally', age: 32 })

CREATE (john:Person { name: 'John', age: 27 })

MATCH (sally {name: 'Sally'}), (john {name: 'John'})
  CREATE (sally)-[:FRIEND_OF { since: 1357718400 }]->(john)
```

Of course, the latter approach assumes that names are unique identifiers, which is not true in general. To work around this, you can:

- return the node identifiers using the [`ID()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#_node_id) function and use `MATCH (sally), (john) WHERE ID(sally) = ..., ID(john) = ...` or
- use some other identifier from outside the database (social security number, etc.).